# is there Resource.designer.cs file in dotnet Maui project?

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui, .net-maui, zebra-scanners

im new to dotnet maui and im trying to add a Resource.designer class file to import some code generated in a xamarin project " Zebra scan App " , so could you please help and tell me what's the alternative for this file resource.designer in maui please ..

I tried adding the file in the project root but i got like + 3000 error because of some global:: ... I tried adding the xamarin nuget packages too but nothing

Comment: instead of vaguely describing the error "3000 error because of some global" it is a lot more helpful to actually include the specific error message

Comment: **1)** Don't add xamarin nugets to a Maui project. That cannot work. **2)** Show a few lines of the file you are trying to add. Is it a `Xamarin.Android` "Resource.Designer.cs" file, with lines similar to `public const int Textview=0x7f050000;`? If so, that is a) meaningless by itself - depends on Android `.axml`s and b) only works with Android UI elements; it is not cross-platform; you won't be able to use it. **3)** Explain the larger goal that you are trying to accomplish. From what you have said so far, you might have to re-do this part of it from scratch, to have a cross-platform app.

Comment: Like ToolmakerSteve said, NuGet package for Xamarin doesn't work for Maui.